# Pandas: How to create True/False column that check existing row with certain values in the previous weeks?

Tags: python, pandas

Could you please help?

This is my dataframe.

| Branch name | WeekStart | Product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple Store | 01/11/2021 00:00:00 | Apple Iphone XR 64 gb |
| Apple Store | 01/11/2021 00:00:00 | Apple Iphone 11 128 gb |
| T mobile | 01/11/2021 00:00:00 | Apple Iphone 13 Pro 256 gb |
| T mobile | 01/11/2021 00:00:00 | Apple Iphone 12 256 gb |
| Apple Store | 08/11/2021 00:00:00 | Apple Iphone XR 64 gb |
| Apple Store | 08/11/2021 00:00:00 | Apple Iphone 11 128 gb |
| T mobile | 15/11/2021 00:00:00 | Apple Iphone 13 Pro 256 gb |
| T mobile | 15/11/2021 00:00:00 | Apple Iphone 12 256 gb |
| Apple Store | 15/11/2021 00:00:00 | Apple Iphone XR 64 gb |
| Apple Store | 15/11/2021 00:00:00 | Apple Iphone 11 128 gb |
| T mobile | 22/11/2021 00:00:00 | Apple Iphone 13 Pro 256 gb |
| T mobile | 22/11/2021 00:00:00 | Apple Iphone 12 256 gb |
| Apple Store | 22/11/2021 00:00:00 | Apple Iphone XR 64 gb |
| Apple Store | 22/11/2021 00:00:00 | Apple Iphone 11 128 gb |

I want to create a new column that will tell me exists in a certain outlet a specific product in the past 3 weeks inclusive.
If there was no product in the certain outlet last 3 weeks then false.

| Branch name | WeekStart | Product | Exists prev 3week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple Store | 22/11/2021 00:00:00 | Apple Iphone XR 64 gb | True |
| Apple Store | 22/11/2021 00:00:00 | Apple Iphone 11 128 gb | True |
| T mobile | 22/11/2021 00:00:00 | Apple Iphone 13 Pro 256 gb | False |
| T mobile | 22/11/2021 00:00:00 | Apple Iphone 12 256 gb | False |

How can I do this?

I tried to no avail:

```
def prev_3week(x):
    if (x - pd.DateOffset(weeks=3) in x.values) & (x - pd.DateOffset(weeks=2) in x.values) & (x - pd.DateOffset(weeks=1) in x.values):
        return True #considering day greater than 14 as third week 
    else:
        return False
df['Exists prev 3week'] = df.groupby(['Branch name'])['WeekStart'].apply(lambda x: prev_3week(x)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your dataframe is already sorted by `WeekStart` column and have the data type `datetime64`.

Try:

```
# If it's not already the case, comment out this lines
# df['WeekStart'] = pd.to_datetime(df['WeekStart'], dayfirst=True)
# df = df.sort_values('WeekStart')

consecutive_week = lambda x, n: x.sub(x.shift()).eq(pd.Timedelta(days=7))[-n:].all()

out = df.groupby(['Branch name', 'Product']).agg(**{
    'WeekStart': ('WeekStart', 'last'),
    'Exists prev 3week': ('WeekStart', lambda x: consecutive_week(x, n=3)),
    'Exists prev 2week': ('WeekStart', lambda x: consecutive_week(x, n=2))
}).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   Branch name                     Product  WeekStart  Exists prev 3week  Exists prev 2week
0  Apple Store      Apple Iphone 11 128 gb 2021-11-22               True               True
1  Apple Store       Apple Iphone XR 64 gb 2021-11-22               True               True
2     T mobile      Apple Iphone 12 256 gb 2021-11-22              False              False
3     T mobile  Apple Iphone 13 Pro 256 gb 2021-11-22              False              False
```

Comment: Does it solve your problem?